# how to secure api call from proxy

Tags: ios, http, https, afnetworking, android-async-http

I am working on some app which as API call. while i add proxy in mobile and see response in web debugging tools. I can see my api call parameters and response too. 
[image]

while in others app I cant see this things and it is secured.

[image]

how can i acheive this?

Comment: are you hitting HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: http can also give same secured data for communication.

Comment: are these QueryString parameters? which method you are using to hit API?

Comment: method - GET/POST both. I am using Rest and SOAP api both. and parameter are in json format and query string both. in different different api. I can see all parameters in parameters and everything like header body and response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pictures said your API is using non-secure HTTP protocol while others app using HTTPS. The Web API should be performed via HTTPS protocol. HTTPS using SSL/TLS as secure transport layer, it means all data are encrypted before they're online. So, we don't care about any kinds of proxy